# Tomcat8: 404 error although webapp folder exists (dspace instances)

Tags: java, tomcat, http-status-code-404, tomcat8, dspace

Using tomcat-8.0.32 on Ubuntu 16.04.
I have configured `/etc/tomcat8/server.xml` to allow access to 2 different dspace instances as follows:

```
<!-- DSpace Instance A -->
<Context path="/dspaceA" docBase="/home/pkaramol/Workspace/dspace/dspace-installation/webapps/jspui" reloadable="true" />
<Context path="/solr" docBase="/home/pkaramol/Workspace/dspace/dspace-installation/webapps/solr" reloadable="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"    allow="my\.static\.ip\.addr|127\.0\.0\.1|123\.123\.123\.123|111\.222\.233\.d+"/>
    <Parameter name="LocalHostRestrictionFilter.localhost" value="false" override="false" />               
</Context>


<!-- DSpace Instance B -->
<Context path="/dspaceB" docBase="/home/pkaramol/Workspace/tomcat-deployments/dspaceB" >
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="my\.static\.ip\.addr|127\.0\.0\.1|123\.123\.123\.123|111\.222\.233\.d+"/>
    <Parameter name="LocalHostRestrictionFilter.localhost" value="false" override="false" /> 
</Context>
```

However, although instance A is accessible, instance B returns a 404 error.
The weird thing is that on `catalina.out` I get a WARNING about instance B.

> WARNING: The web application [dspaceB] appears to have started a
>   thread named [TestScheduler_Worker X] but has failed to stop it. This
>   is very likely to crreate a memory leak.

The warning is repeated for 1 <= X <= 50.

So webapp dspaceB is indeed recognized by tomcat8.

How come the `404` error?

edit: some new findings:

when deleting the DSpace Instance B entry from `server.xml` and moving it to the default webapps deployment dir for tomcat8 (`/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/`), I no longer get a `404` error but rather a `Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception and a constant

> > Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing

warning on `catalina.out`

Answer (score 1):

No idea about your specific issue -- but DSpace (at least the 6.0 release candidates) is [known](https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-3142) to have problems with that exact tomcat version. Perhaps that's related.